# Ugly experience with Command Pattern: Any point in OOP?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, messaging, command-pattern

I have implemented a command pattern in my system, mostly because I have several tiers and I need to 'invoke' logic remotely.

```
class DoWorkCommandMessage { int param; }

class DoWorkCommandHandler : Handler<DoWorkCommandMessage>
{
    Execute(MyObject object) {
       object.DoWork(message.param);
    }
}

class MyObject
{
    void DoWork(int param) {
        _proxy.SendMessage(new DoWorkBinaryMessage(param));
    }
}
```

As you can see I am basically getting a message, converting it into a method call, which is then converting it back to a message which is sent to another tier.

I feel like there is something wrong here.

I ended up refactoring MyObject to remove all the methods and replaced them with a simple ProcessMessage method which takes a message, translates it, then dispatches it.

This was OK except the MyObject ended up being mostly just transformation code, not an 'object'...

In order to unit test I have to keep calling ProcessMessage() instead of making a straightforward method call.

I am looking for thoughts on this battle between "messaging & transformations" vs "messages -> method -> messages" approach. Obviously messages and methods are very closely related.

Comment: Why can't you have behaviour or logic in MyObject? Can your "MyObject" be more specific and perform some logic instead of standing in as a proxy?

Comment: The MyObject is actually an "object" representing a bit of hardware out in the field. The server has many such objects because we have thousands of hardware devices in the field. The actual hardware device holds most of the state, we send it messages, and essentially cache its most recent state in the server. I am torn on whether to model this device in an OOP fashion or just not bother... its only when writing Unit tests its nice to have methods, otherwise they are not used at all

Comment: It always depend on what you are trying to achieve. It seems in your case you didn't need it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the confusion and/or difficulty is that you are not actually using the Command Pattern.  You mixing it with Messaging.  You can even see this in the name of your Command...`DoWorkCommandMessage`.  In a classic Command pattern, the work is actually done by the Command object.  In a messaging approach, the messages are are passed around as a DTO and are executed by handlers.

To further illustrate, I have an application that uses

```
AbstractCommand
+ Execute()
+ CanUndo()
+ Undo()
+ CanChain(cmd)
+ Chain(cmd)
```

A concrete instance of that class is:

```
MoveUnitCommand  // a unit is a graphic piece on a game board
+ UnitId
+ Destination
+ Execute()
  {
      units = Units.Find(UnitId)
      prevCoords = units.Position
      units.Position = Destination
  }
+ CanUndo() { return true; }
+ Undo()
  {
      units = Units.Find(UnitId)
      units.Position = prevCoords 
  }
+ etc, etc
```

Note that the command subclass does not just describe what to do, it actually acts upon your system state.

Comment: In order to remote a command you need to use messaging. Are you saying commands can never be remoted? This is where u end up using the command handler pattern. Command is split into its data (message) and code  (handler) parts. In my qn I am anguishing over the fact my "object" ends up forwarding command messages to another tier. I am having an existential crisis on whether this this is really an object... do I need to convert the message to an method only to send the message to another tier? If not I end up with an anemic object. Perhaps that is OK..I am looking for advice (moral support!?)

Comment: My response was more a comment on callingwhat you have coded a use of the "Command Pattern".  It is not really, at least in a classic sense (though all pattern usage has shade of gray).  To address your other concerns, I have a follow up question.  Are all of your "commands" really just messages being sent out of processes (remoted)?  If so, I'd refactor them to just Messages and forget that Command related code.  I would probably consider seperating the Message from the implementation of the serialization, allowing you to support multiple "protocols" on the wire, if that is likely needed.